# Use Google Apps Script to Print Datastudio

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api, looker-studio

I'm trying to automate the process of saving a PDF version of a daily Datastudio report to Google Drive. I found this helpful bit of code that uses Google Apps Script to save a Google Doc as a pdf in Drive: https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/dbe99c193e5b6b0c7b61

But when I try to use this process for a Datastudio file, I get an error saying:

"Converting from application/vnd.google-analytics.rap.report to application/pdf is not supported."

Does anyone know a way to get around this?

Comment: Data Studio reports aren't Google Docs. The only tool I have found is a Chrome extension called Google Data Studio PDF Export, but the quality of the output is pretty rubbish, and anyway you want to automate it. I can only suggest using the Google Sheets GA plugin instead of Data Studio, if feasible, and then you could use your Google Apps script. There are many occasions when I wish we had to pay a little bit for Data Studio, then we could expect it to fit better into normal IT life!

Answer (score 0):

You may check the new e-mail delivery feature of DataStudio.

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9263641

You can schedule daily or weekly delivery to a dedicated mail address and connect this mail address to IFTTT to save mail content to the Google Drive.

Sample workflow may be followed like this;

1. Data Studio E-mail delivery sends report as mail
2. IFTTT takes mail (This step can be defined as: If mail from **data-studio-noreply@google.com**)

   3. IFTTT sends mail to webhook (When you deploy your Apps Script project as a web project, Apps script gives you a request url, you can configure your apps script project which handles mail body and saves as a file)

An image may be helpful;

[IFTTT workflow sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvZBL.png)

Answer (score -1):

This is not officially supported (July 2018).